# django-channels add user to multiple groups on connect

Tags: django, django-channels

So I have my models like this.

```py
class Box(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [name, owner, icon]

class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    objects = BaseUserManager()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, validators=[MinLengthValidator(2)], unique=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/', default='avatars/default.jpg')

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [username, email]

class Member(models.Model):

    objects = models.Manager()
    box = models.ForeignKey('uploads.Box', on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=False)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField('roles.Role', through='roles.MemberRole')
    invite = models.ForeignKey('users.Invite', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [box, user]
```

I have a websockets framework with routing like this.

```py
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('gateway/', GatewayEventsConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

```py
class GatewayEventsConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    """
    An ASGI consumer for gateway event sending. Any authenticated
    user can connect to this consumer. Users receive personalized events
    based on the permissions they have.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    async def connect(self):
        user = self.scope['user']
        if user.is_anonymous:
            # close the connection if the
            # user isn't authenticated yet
            await self.close()

        for member in user.member_set.all():
            # put user into groups according to the boxes
            # they are a part of. Additional groups would be
            # added mid-way if the user joins or creates
            # a box during the lifetime of this connection
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(member.box.id, self.channel_name)
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.scope['user'].id, self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        for member in self.scope['user'].member_set.all():
            # remove user from groups according to the boxes they
            # are a part of. Additional groups would be
            # removed mid-way if the user leaves or gets kicked
            # out of a box during the lifetime of this connection
            await self.channel_layer.group_discard(member.box.id, self.channel_name)
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.scope['user'].id, self.channel_name)

    async def fire_event(self, event: dict):
        formatted = {
            'data': event['data'],
            'event': event['event'],
        }
        box = event.get('box', None)
        channel = event.get('overwrite_channel', None)
        listener_perms = event.get('listener_permissions', [])
        if not listener_perms or not box:
            # box would be none if the event was user-specific
            # don't need to check permissions. Fan-out event
            # directly before checking member-permissions
            return await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(formatted))
        member = self.scope['user'].member_set.get(box=box)
        if listener_perms in member.get_permissions(channel):
            # check for permissions directly without any extra context
            # validation. Because data-binding is outbound permission
            # checking is not complex, unlike rest-framework checking
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(formatted))
```

this is how I send ws messages.
(using django signals)

```py
@receiver(post_delete, sender=Upload)
def on_upload_delete(instance=None, **kwargs) -> None:
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
        instance.box.id,
        {
            'type': 'fire_event',
            'event': 'UPLOAD_DELETE',
            'listener_permissions': ['READ_UPLOADS'],
            'overwrite_channel': instance.channel,
            'box': instance.box,
            'data': PartialUploadSerializer(instance).data
        }
    )
```

The api needs to send box-specific events, so I have different groups for boxes.
Users which connect to these groups will receive the events they need.

So, when the user connects to the "gateway", I add the user to all the boxes they are a part of, (plus a private group to send user-specific information)

On disconnect, I remove them from the same.
However, I am facing issues here.
An example,

- when an user joins a box during the scope of the connection, they would not receive the events that are being sent for that particular box.
- when an user leaves a box during the scope of the connection, they would still receive events from that  particular box.

Any ways to fix these issues?
relevant github discussion is [here](https://github.com/django/channels/discussions/1636).

Comment: Don't the 2 examples you gave contradict themselves? In the first case you're saying they don't receive the events, and in the second you're saying they continue to receive the events. How can they continue receiving the events if they never got them in the first place?

Comment: When the user leaves the box during the scope of the connection but were added before

Comment: Ok, got that. Just add a handler methods (similar to fire event) that add a user to a group or remove them from group. Then send a was message to that handler from your code whenever the user becomes a member of the box and vice versa. You can use Django signals

Comment: thanks a lot! mind putting it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: done! check it below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding 2 handlers similar to `fire-event`.

1. The first one adds a user to a group
2. The second one deletes a user from a group.

Then using Django Signals, send a websocket message to those handlers whenever a user becomes a box member or leaves the box